# How to clean all whitespace characters from a large string?

Tags: c#, string, visual-studio, html-agility-pack

I have received a string from the Html Agility Pack - it's cleaned and doesn't have tags:

```
string cleanText = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.InnerText;
```

Now my question is: How to clean all whitespace characters such as new lines, etc..?

Example string:

```
                                                                                       
@Vanni                                                                                       
                                                breitbart.com

                                                #swiat
                                                #usa
                                                #youtube
                                                #technologia
                                                +2 inne






                                        Akcja &quot;They can't silence us&quot; ma związek z pozwem wytoczonym przeciwko YouTube przez kanał PragerU za bezpodstawne zablokowanie konta.
```

I need a string like:

> @Vannibreitbart.com#swiat#usa#youtube#technologia+2inneAkcja"Theycan'tsilenceus"mazwiązekzpozwemwytoczonymprzeciwkoYouTubeprzezkanałPragerUzabezpodstawnezablokowaniekonta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex is probably as easy as any:

```
string compressed = Regex.Replace(bigstring, @"\s+", "");
```

You could also perhaps iterate it as a chararray and only load those chars where Char.IsWhitespace() returns false, into a string builder

Comment: Use `@"\s+"` and make it greedy. Also there's only a few hundred steps involved as your solution there's over a thousand steps; very inefficient.

Comment: Also with the current string, your approach would be matching over 400 times, where as `@"\s+"` would match only 20 something, a significant change; fewer steps == fewer matches and better performance.

Answer (score -1):

Use this to remove the chars, put the char on array to remove. pass the string to method. this a static mehtod

```
  public static string RemoveCharSpecials(string document)
    {
        var charsToRemove = new string[] { "@", ",", ".", ";", "'", "(", ")", "-", " ", "/" };

        try
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(document))
            {
                foreach (var c in charsToRemove)
                    document = document.Replace(c, string.Empty);
            }

            return document;
        }
        catch
        {
            return "";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Catching all exceptions, ignoring them, and then returning an empty string is pretty much the **worst** thing you can do here. I hope you don't actually write production code that does things like this...

Comment: Not to mention you're replacing characters OP wants to keep. Why have a blacklist of characters when they appear to just want to remove whitespace/newlines?

Comment: @BrootsWaymb, in this case this try will never happen

Comment: @CelzioBR - Doesn't mean it's not terrible coding practice. But yes, it shouldn't even be here anyway.

Comment: @CodeStranger this is to remove whatever character you want, it fits all

Comment: @BrootsWaymb, why not?, it's works very well ;D

Comment: @CelzioBR - Because it both serves no purpose and is terrible exception handling practice. Just because it doesn't cause problems in this case doesn't means it's good. It does not "work very well".